# Should you autosave when app is minimized?

Tags: data, save, data-entry, data-collection, autosave

I'm developing an Android app that allows users to fill out different types of forms (input types = text, numbers, and sliders for certain numbers).

The save button is in the top-right corner, in the action bar. When the user fills out the entire form (~15 input fields), the user might accidentally press the back button and lose all data that was inputted. Hence, we're autosaving on back button press.

**Should I also auto save forms when the user presses the Android home button?**

To clarify, autosave implies auto submit - the form is saved to the server (in contrast to just keeping data persistent on the phone until the user submits).

---

I'm leaning towards not autosaving on home button press because it is possible the user simply wants to cancel the input process. In this case, autosaving would lead to incorrect behaviour.

Comment: Have you asked any users of your app what they would expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the behaviour to be the opposite of what you're saying... When I press back I'd expect some kind of warning about my data being "reset". When I press home I expect the form to stay as it is. I might need to switch between app to look up some values you're asking, so that won't be possible then?